# How to add e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to stop the page jumping to the top of the page where #soundEvent is located when the Play function s executed. According to this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/1998717/511438, it is caused by the `.html()` and `.append()`; The page can be prevented from "jumping" by using e.preventDefault() or return false (false did not work). How can I use preventDefault?

I have the following in my document.Ready

```
$("[data-play-sound]").each(
    function ()
    {
        var soundFile = $(this).attr('data-play-sound');
        if (soundFile != "") Play(soundFile);
        $(this).removeAttr('data-play-sound');
    }
);

function Play(mp3Path)
{
    $("#sound_").remove();
    console.groupCollapsed(' ');
    $('#soundEvent').append('<embed id="sound_" autostart="true" hidden="true" src="' + mp3Path + '" type="audio/mpeg" />');
    console.groupEnd();
}
```

I have tried this but result in error: Object '0' has not method preventDefault

```
   $("[data-play-sound]").each(
        function (e)
        {
            ...
            if (soundFile != "") Play(e, soundFile);
            ...
        }
    );

function Play(e, mp3Path)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
}
```

Comment: when is the jumping happening? is it when you click on a element or triggered by some other user interaction from the users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jQuery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) takes parameters index and value, not event so `0` would mean index

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault` only works with event handlers (`return false` is an alternate way of canceling events), e.g. `$('#myLink').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

You don't actually have any event handlers set up here...if you can select your links via a class, then you could do something like:

`$('.someClass').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Or you can just add `onclick="return false;"` (i.e. do nothing) to the link tags. It would be helpful to see your HTML to determine whether you really need to be putting in `href="#soundEvent"` in the first place.